# Get values from DOM and pass to a function

Tags: javascript

So I am writing the following function in Javascript.

```
function storeBooking (firstname, lastname, age, species, is1day, is4day, is10day)  {
    var trip = ""
    if(is1day) trip ="1 day";
    if(is4day)+=", 4 days";
    if(is10day) += ", 10 days";
    sessionStorage.trip = trip;
    sessionStorage.firstname = firstname;
    sessionStorage.lastname = lastname;
    sessionStorage.age = age;
    sessionStorage.species = species;

    alert ("Trip storage: " + sessionStorage.trip); 
}
```

My task is to ensure the function stores user information input in sessionStorage – that is firstname, lastname, age, species, trip, food and partySize.  However, food and partySize are not to be passed as function parameters. However, I am not sure how to get those values from DOM.

HTML 1

```
<label for="food">Menu preferences</label>
        <select name="food" id="food">
            <option value="none">Please select</option>
            <option value="lembas">Lembas</option>
            <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
            <option value="ent">Ent Draft</option>
            <option value="cram">Cram</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="partySize">Number of Travellers</label>
            <input type="text" id="partySize" name="partySize" maxlength="3" size="3" />
    </p>
```

HTML 2 where data must be transferred

```
<input type="hidden" name="food" id="food" />
<input type="hidden" name="partySize" id="partySize" />
```

Comment: That depends on where these values are.  Where are they?  Do you have a more complete example?

Comment: Hi @David, I am trying to transfer data from one HTML file to another using sessionStorage in Javascript. I have updated the question to include the parts of two htmls I want to transfer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify parameters, you can get direct inside function by

```
var food = document.getElementById("food").value;
        var partySize= document.getElementById("partySize").value;  




function storeBooking (firstname, lastname, age, species, is1day, is4day, is10day)  {
        var food = document.getElementById("food").value;
        var partySize= document.getElementById("partySize").value;
        var trip = ""
        if(is1day) trip ="1 day";
        if(is4day)+=", 4 days";
        if(is10day) += ", 10 days";
        sessionStorage.trip = trip;
        sessionStorage.firstname = firstname;
        sessionStorage.lastname = lastname;
        sessionStorage.age = age;
        sessionStorage.species = species;

        alert ("Trip storage: " + sessionStorage.trip); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete because of the lack of the source of data, but i will try to guess your case to help you.

I suppose you have a form with some fields, it shows up to the user to fill these fields with a necessary information. right?, and then you need to get user inputs from the DOM.

```
<form>
     <label>First Name</label><br>
     <input type="text" id="firstName" size="30"> <br>

     <label>Last Name</label><br>
     <input type="text" id="lastName" size="30"> <br>

     <label>Age</label><br>
     <input type="text" id="age" size="30"> <br>

     <label>Species</label><br>
     <input type="text" id="species" size="30"> <br>

     <label>days</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="days"  value="1 day"> one day <br>
     <input type="radio" name="days"  value="4 days"> four days <br>
     <input type="radio" name="days"  value="10 days"> ten days <br>

    <input type="button" value="save" onclick="storeBooking()"/>


</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  function storeBooking ()  {
        sessionStorage.trip=document.querySelector('input[name="days"]:checked').value;               
        sessionStorage.firstname = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
        sessionStorage.lastname = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
        sessionStorage.age = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
        sessionStorage.species = species;

        alert ("Trip storage: " + sessionStorage.trip); 
 }
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't see your question's updates until my answer submitted. :-)